# Handle is semi-closed error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, handle

I am getting this error in GHCI :

`*** Exception: <stdin>: hGetLine: illegal operation (handle is semi-closed)`

After running this code :

```
main = do
    interact $ unlines . fmap proccess . take x . lines
    readLn :: IO Int
```

And I am pretty sure the cause is `take x`. Is there any better way to read **only** x lines of input using interact **or** is `interact` just a solo player?

Comment: `interact` puts stdin into a semi-closed state. I assume your function worked correctly the first time, and every other invocation after that failed? Either close and reopen GHCi or compile your program and execute it.

Comment: Exactly, every read of `stdin` failed afterwards.

Comment: As a side note, is it possible to reopen closed handle to stdin in other way but closing and reopening ghci?

Comment: As @RowanBlush indicated, the `stdin` handle is put in a semi closed state by `interact` or any function which reads the entirety of stdin. Remember, your GHCI session is basically one big do block - and writing `main = getContents >> getContents` is equally as invalid. If you want to read `n` lines, just use `replicateM n getLine{readLn/whatever}` - using a function which reads all of stdin will always close stdin afterwards. You cannot "reopen" `stdin` - it is just a unix file descriptor under the hood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with `interact`. Behind the scenes `interact` claims the entirety of `stdin` for itself with [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents). This puts the handle into a “semi-closed” state, preventing you from attempting any further interaction with the handle besides closing it, as the entirety of its input has already been consumed (lazily).

Try reading a finite number of lines with—

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

getLines :: Int -> IO [String]
getLines n = replicateM n getLine
```

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually `interact` consumes *all* of standard input. So it doesn't make any sense to call `readLn` afterwards.

To only read a given number of lines, use something like:

```
import Control.Monad

main = do input <- replicateM 10 getLine
          ...
```

Here `input` will be a list of (exactly) 10 Strings.

Things get more complicated if you want to allow for fewer lines or if you want to stop reading when you encounter a special condition.