# Reading stdin in ghci on Linux is broken

Tags: linux, bash, haskell

Comming from Windows, I have recently installed linux distribution named Peppermint and Haskell-Platform via bash (ghc 7.10) but there must be something wrong with ghci stdin in ghci because :

`interact $ take 0`
throws an error but
`interact $ take 1`
does not.

Furthermore, if I use `backspace`, `arrows` or any other control button when writing into stdin, it *enters the char symbol*. For example backspace **enters `^?`** into ghci **instead of deleting** the last char typed...

> ```
> ...@... ~ $ ghci
> GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> Prelude> interact $ take 0
> Prelude> 
> <stdin>: hGetChar: illegal operation (handle is closed)
> ...@... ~ $ ghci
> GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> Prelude> readLn :: IO String 
> euoe^?^?^[[1;5C^[[D^[[B -- here I tried to delete 'euoe'
> ```

Comment: How are you running the program? Also what are you expecting to happen? GHCI seems to execute anything piped in so I'm not sure you could ever re-read stdin.

Comment: This looks related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776023/handle-is-semi-closed-error-in-haskell

Comment: `interact` and GHCi do not mix well, IIRC. `interact` wants ALL the stdin for itself, and GHCi can not get it back.

Comment: @villou24 not really, because I did not try to read from stdin twice.

Comment: @FordO. The suggestion is that you implicitly tried to read from stdin twice - once for the REPL (ghci) and once for your explicit `interact` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the control code literals, this is because you've managed to escape all of the line editors (readline, Haskeline) that would usually interpret your key presses.

I don't know the particulars, but invoking GHCi is something like starting a subshell with `bash --noediting`. This allows GHCi to receive raw key presses without interference from the readline library. This is done because Haskeline—which GHCi uses in place of readline—can be configured with things like tab completion for available functions more easily (you knew GHCi provided tab completion, right?).

Calling `getLine` from GHCi then effectively drops through a trap door and dodges Haskeline completely by going straight to stdin. There is, after all, only one stdin. You're now typing directly into an unbuffered terminal.

Getting back to your first concern, there being only one stdin is also why GHCi immediately keels over after printing the `Prelude>` prompt. `interact` (which uses `hGetContents` behind the scenes) claims that it will address all of the input that will ever come through the handle (stdin) as one big lazy `String`. Effectively there can be no remaining input on the handle that `interact` hasn't already claimed to deal with, so the handle is immediately put into a “semi-closed” state. It's not closed (there could still be more input that will be read as part of that lazy `String` `interact` gets!) but it *is* closed to any newcomers, otherwise input would get duplicated (`interact` and new readers of the handle such as `getLine` would get the same line!).

Back to GHCi, after having used `interact`, stdout is still fine so the prompt gets printed as usual, then GHCi leans on Haskeline to return a line for processing. Haskeline (as a line editor) calls a blocking `getChar` (iirc) to either add a character to the line or perform some line editing command and dies because it's addressing a semi-closed handle. Thus a weaker creature does fall and the great wheel of life rolls on.

Comment: Thanks, The control code literals are really pain, because I cant make any typo... Windows ghci somehow managed to interpret them in the right way so I am confused why linux ghci cannot.